# How to install a brightness indicator in unity?

Tags: unity, brightness, chromebook, crouton

I have installed ubuntu in my chromebook (toshiba 2) and the brightness and volumen keys are working correctly. I did not have to install anything. I just changed the shortcuts. However, although I can see the brightness changing, I want to see an indicator to know where in the brightness scale I am. 
Where can I download this indicator from?

Comment: I answered your question, please check if it works for you and/or report possible issues.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no `indicator-brightness` package directly on main repos, you'll have to add the *[ppa](https://launchpad.net/~indicator-brightness/+archive/ubuntu/ppa) (Personal Package Archive)* from its developers.

#### Adding the PPA

Run the following command in your terminal to add the ppa:

`sudo add-apt-repository ppa:indicator-brightness/ppa`

You'll be prompted to accept adding the *ppa*, press `Y` and *(or simply)* `Enter` to accept.

#### Install *indicator-brightness*

First, you need to update you package info after adding the ppa, so run this from your terminal:

`sudo apt update`

Next you can install *indicator-brightness* by simply running:

`sudo apt install indicator-brightness`

*Then you can launch the indicator from Unity's Dash, add it to your startup applications, etc.*

Hope it helps.

Comment: While this does seem to work, it is so ugly and unhandy that I preferred not to have a brightness indicator instead.